# How to render with EJS the result of a Mongodb query using Express and Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, underscore.js, ejs

I am trying to avoid creating db queries everytime I use
`router.get("/whatever",function()...)`

so I created a `dbController` which returns an array of documents by means of
`db.collection.find().toArray()`

which is working fine . 
I choked here though

```
router.get( "/test" , function ( req , res , err ) {
        if (err) console.dir( err );

    var categoriesArray = require ( "./Controllers/dbController" ).getCategsArray();

    console.log( "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + categoriesArray );

    res.render( "hello" , {
                _: _ ,
            title: "la naiba" ,
            items: categoriesArray
        });
    });
```

because although  the console.log shows the documents array

```
[Function: next]
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
[ { _id: ObjectID { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: 'QrÑUÿY?ó#M_?' },
    categories: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    id: 'mens',
    name: 'Mens',
    page_description: 
................................
```

I am not geting it in the EJS template

```
..............................................
<% _.each(items, function(topC) { %>
<li>
    <h1><%= topC.name %></h1>
..........................
```

`title property` though gets rendered. Any help is greatly appreciated since I'm a complete n00b and I've lost all night trying to make progress

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name and list to interate is inside *categoriesArray*, then you need to interate categoriesArray. Somelike this:

```
<% items.forEach(function (topC) { %>
    <li>  
        <h1><%= topC.name %></h1>  
    </li>                                   
<% }) %>
```

Comment: Much kudos Lucas ! Only this works     `<% _.forEach(items, function(topC) { %>`  although underscore [docs](http://underscorejs.org/#each) states that `forEach` is an alias to `each` . I'm buffled

Comment: nice, it's another way =]